# Problema no desenvolvimento do formulário do comments.php do Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Olá! Estou desenvolvendo um tema e meu formulário no *comments.php* está dando erro. O resto da arquivo de comentários está funcionando direito. Estou seguindo o livro "*How To Be a Rockstar Wordpress Designer*" como referência e copiei o código na íntegra. Segue o código:

```
<?php if ($post->comment_status == 'open') : ?>
    <h3>Deixe seu comentário</h3>
<?php if (get_option('comment_registration') && !$user_ID) : ?>
    <p>You must be <a href="<?php bloginfo('url');?>/wp-login.php?redirect_to=<?php the_permanentlink();?>">looged in</a> to post a comment.</p>
<?php else : ?>
<form action="<?php bloginfo('url');?>/wp-comments-post.php" method="post" class="comment-form">
<?php if ( $user_ID) : ?>
    <h4>Logged in as<a href="<?php echo get_option('siteurl');?>/wp-admin/profile.php"><?php echo $user_identity; ?></a>
    <a href="<?php echo get_option('siteurl');?>/wp-login.php?action=logout" title="Log out of this account">Logout</a>
    </h4>
<?php else : ?>
    <input type="text" name="author" id="author" value="<?php echo $comment_author; ?>"/>
    <label for="author"><small>bane <?php if ($req) echo "(required)"; ?></small></label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $comment_author_email; ?>"/>
    <label for="email"><small>Mail (will not be published)<?php if ($req) echo "(required)"?></small></label>   
    <input type="text" name="url" id="url" value="<?php echo $comment_author_url; ?>"/>
    <label for="url"><small>Website</small></label>
<?php endif; ?>
<textarea name="comment" id="data" cols="60" rows="7" tabindex="4"></textarea>
<input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" tabindex="5" value="Submit Comment"/>
<input type="hidden" name="comment_post_ID" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
<?php do_action('comment_form', $post->ID); ?>
</form> <?php endif; ?>
```

Grato desde já.

Estou acrescentando uma imagem para ilustrar o erro, como sugerido nos comentários:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Gostei do nome do livro, parece bem promissor. Qual é o problema que está acontecendo? aparece algum erro? qual?

Comment: Qual o erro que esta aparecendo?

Comment: Obrigado.
Acrescentei uma imagem na pergunta para ilustrar o erro.

Comment: O erro que está sinalizado no arquivo comments.php, linha 66, segundo a imagem. Adicione o código do comments.php.

Comment: @devgaspa , a linha 66 é última, no caso '</form> <?php endif; ?>'
Por isso estou confuso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caro,

Adicione mais um `<?php endif; ?>` no final do seu código, após identar notei a ausência, provavelmente isto gerou o erro.

Abraço.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Funcionou!
Desculpe se minha dúvida foi muito idiota, ainda estou muito no início do PHP.
Abraço.